# Displaying the area in chart below or above threshold value is not working in D3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a D3 chart implemented with React.
I am displaying the area for below or above threshold value which is blue dotted line. But it's not working as expected.

Code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-river-yo0xy).

[image]
Data:

```
var data = [
      {
        startTime: "1570184520049",
        magnitude: -20
      },
      {
        startTime: "1570875720049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1571653320049",
        magnitude: 10
      },
      {
        startTime: "1572517320049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1573467720049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1574504520049",
        magnitude: 10
      },
      {
        startTime: "1575627720049",
        magnitude: 0
      }
    ];
```

My code for area:

```
var area = d3
  .area()
  .x0(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.startTime);
  })
  .x1(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.magnitude);
  })
  .y0(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.magnitude);
  })
  .y1(height);
```

This works fine for the above mentioned data.
But if I have some value (magnitude) for last element of data it doesn't work. And for less data elements it doesn't work.

```
  {
    startTime: "1575627720049",
    magnitude: 10
   }
```

[image]
Can someone tell me what is the problem or where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update `y1` definition for your function as such `.y1(yScale(0))` In this case everything will relate to your absolute `0` on the chart and the first and last point will have origin in scale `0`

full update for area:

```
 var area = d3
      .area()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .y0(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.magnitude);
      })
      .y1(yScale(0));
```

Comment: indeed: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-river-yo0xy?fontsize=14

Comment: @Cornel Thanks, This works, what I understand If later on i have to change my threshold to 10 in place of 0 I have to pass 10.

Comment: I just wanted to know, why my 'yLabel' is not reflecting ? any comments ?

Comment: @JavascriptCoder in order to better understand try replacing `.attr("d", area);` with `.attr("d", line);` the problem is that you have to give it an origin where to start and end. With this in mind your statement that changing the threshold from 0 to 10 is correct. Not really sure what you mean by: ''yLabel' is not reflecting'

Comment: Two observations: since `x0` and `x1` are the same, it can be just `x`. Also, you don't need the unnecessary function for `y1`, it can be just `.y1(yScale(0))`.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado - updated the answer according to your feedback

Comment: @CornelStefanache, sorry for not being clear, by 'yLabel' means - where yLabel is some text - 

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(yLabel);

code for y axis label doesn't reflect, I guess I am missing something, this code works with d3 js Version 3.

Comment: @JavascriptCoder not really sure if this is the desired output but you can use `g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).selectAll("text").text(d => `M: ${d}`);` in order to update the text for each tick - The axis that you have built already has 'text' attr that you can update